# Ошибка ETELEGRAM: 400 Bad Request: message is not modified

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram-bot, telegram

Когда изменяю сообщения бота второй раз, выдается такая ошибка:

> ETELEGRAM: 400 Bad Request: message is not modified

Первый раз всё ок. Как исправить?

```
if(isFav) {
          user.films = user.films.filter(fUUID => fUUID !== filmUUID);
          bot.editMessageCaption('hello',{
            chat_id: chatId,
            message_id: messageId,
            caption: 'asdaasdass',
            reply_markup: {
              inline_keyboard: [
                [
                  {
                    text: 'Добавить',
                    callback_data: JSON.stringify({
                      type: ACTION_TYPE.TOGGLE_FAV_FILM
                    })
                  }
                ]
              ]
            }
          })
        }
        else {
          user.films.push(filmUUID);
          bot.editMessageCaption('bye',{
            chat_id: chatId,
            message_id: messageId,
            caption: 'asdad',
            reply_markup: {
              inline_keyboard: [
                [
                  {
                    text: 'Удалить',
                    callback_data: JSON.stringify({
                      type: ACTION_TYPE.TOGGLE_FAV_FILM
                    })
                  }
                ]
              ]
            }
          })
        }
```

Comment: А у вас `chat_id` и `message_id` заполнены во время второго редактирования?

Comment: [https://github.com/deebov/telegram-bot-for-looking-for-films/blob/master/index.js] ссылка на index.js

Comment: Просто 400 ошибка говорит о том, что запрос не обработан по причине какой-то ошибки в этом запросе. Вам нужно посмотреть на запрос, который вы отправляете, на его параметры, может что-то не заполенно или потерялось? За ссылку спасибо, но пока нужно просто посмотреть, что все же отправляется в первом случае, и что во втором (не рабочем) и сравнить. Просто залогируйте в консоль хотя бы.

Comment: Осмелюсь предположить, что вы просто отправляете запрос на модификацию сообщения, но по сути ничего не изменили в отправленном запросе, отсюда и ошибка, которая говорит, что запрос не верный и сообщение не изменено